# Как решить NetworkOnMainThreadException?

Tags: java, android

Помогите разобраться с [первым тестовым проектом](https://github.com/StekolschikovV/ytranslate).

Файлы: [YandexTranslate.java](https://github.com/StekolschikovV/ytranslate/blob/master/app/src/main/java/info/stekolschikov/ytranslate/YandexTranslate.java) и [MainActivity.java](https://github.com/StekolschikovV/ytranslate/blob/master/app/src/main/java/info/stekolschikov/ytranslate/MainActivity.java)

Вылетает ошибка NetworkOnMainThreadException. Как я понимаю она обычно бывает в том случае когда обращение к интернету в main. Я вынес ее в отделенный класс, почему у меня появляется эта ошибка? Как исправить?

Из консоли:

> 09-07 13:46:04.796 25701-25701/info.stekolschikov.ytranslate E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: info.stekolschikov.ytranslate, PID: 25701
>   android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>   at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1166)
>   at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
>   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
>   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
>   at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
>   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
>   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
>   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
>   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
>   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
>   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
>   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:217)
>   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
>   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
>   at info.stekolschikov.ytranslate.YandexTranslate.translate(YandexTranslate.java:58)
>   at info.stekolschikov.ytranslate.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:40)
>   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4851)
>   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20016)
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5429)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:947)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:742)

Comment: Потому что нужно в отдельном потоке это делать. Используйте, к примеру, `AsyncTask`

Comment: Прежде, чем задавать вопрос, вы **обязаны** воспользоваться поиском http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=NetworkOnMainThreadException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простой пример:

1 Создаете класс (в примере вложенный)

```
private class MyTextLoader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //запустить индикацию загрузки
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        return null;
        //params[0] - Ваша ссылка
        //Получение данных
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        //завершить индикацию загрузки
        //Устанавливаете необходимый текст
    }
}
```

2 Запускаете когда необходимо:

```
MyTextLoader textLoader = new MyTextLoader();
textLoader.execute("Ссылка");
```